# Как называется error.name при ошибках сети? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, браузер, type-error

Мне надо написать обработку ошибок для веб-приложения. Я хочу сделать отдельную обработку для ошибок валидации url, отдельную для ошибок парсинга и отдельную для ошибок сети, поскольку разные типы ошибок предполагают разные реакции. Я перехватываю ошибку с помощью catch(err) и далее в зависимости от того, что содержится в err.name, запускаю разную обработку. Скажем, если это ошибка валидации, то err.name будет равна 'ValidationError', и я выведу сообщение о том, что введённый адрес неправильный, либо что он уже вводился раньше, смотря что конкретно за ошибка.
Проблема в том, что я не знаю как вызвать у себя ошибку сети, чтобы посмотреть в консоли, какой у такой ошибки будет err.name.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Что такое error? В браузерах не существует никакого ValidationError

Comment: error - этот тот объект, который выбрасывается при какой-либо ошибке и перехватывается с помощью catch.

Comment: Этот объект может быть абсолютно любым. В браузере не существует никакого ValidationError — значит ошибки у вас выбрасывает какой-то сторонний код, значит обращайтесь к документации этого стороннего кода

Comment: «я не знаю как вызвать у себя ошибку сети» — вы не можете отключить интернет на своём компьютере? Расскажите как вы это сделали, я тоже хочу у себя иметь интернет, который невозможно отключить :)